# scrollTop in div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrolltop

I have a tried and tested bit of code that has always worked well for me but I'm trying something new with it. I'm not using the body's scroll position but instead I have a div with the ID of `#main` that has an overflow of auto.

The problem I'm having is that when you click a page link (from either inside or outside the `#main` div) the page moves but not to the correct position. What could be causing this issue

```
$('.scrollto').click(function() {
       var elementClicked = $(this).attr("href");
       var destination = $(elementClicked).offset().top;
       $("#main:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination} );
       return false;
});
```

Here's `#main`'s CSS:

```
#main { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

**EDIT**

With a little bit of help from @Moje, I have recreated the issue here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbLyJ

Click the "Click me to go to Target 1" link. Within that section you'll see another link to go to Target 2. Click that and it won't fully go down to the correct ID. If you keep clicking that same link the page will go up and down each time you do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your codepen example and I noticed an error. The error is that you didn't add the actual scroll value. A simple example is that when you click and the scrollTop value is 0, it works fine, but when the scrollTop value is not 0 the `destination` value is not the same as the `destination` value when the scroll is 0.
You can see the forked example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FjKks).
Also, I recommend you to use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`, to avoid the haschange or the URL redirecting.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to work for me. Codepen -> http://codepen.io/mrmoje/pen/waBls

## EDIT:

I edited my pen with your example & saw what you meant. (I also renamed some vars to reflect their true purpose)
So...., after logging the resulting `scrolltop` values in animate's callback, I found that `#main`'s true target scrollTop value should be that of the target element's `offset().top` + the current (or pre-scroll) `$(#main').scrollTop()`.

Checkout [the updated pen](http://codepen.io/mrmoje/pen/waBls) to see what I mean.

Comment: Its an odd one because the very first link works and always scrolls to the correct ID, however if I click a second one its like the code is getting the wrong scroll position. Is this possible?

Comment: I've updated the pen with multiple `scrollto`s and targets. The pen still works as expected. Also make sure your target ids are UNIQUE

Comment: I think I've managed to replicate the issue using your code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbLyJ Click the Go to Target 1, then in the paragraph text you'll see another link to Target 2. Click that and it won't fully go down to the correct section. Then keep clicking it and the page will go up and down each time you do it.